# Reduce URL and label for breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have

```
const url = "/aaa/222/ccc"
const label = "/aaa/bbb/ccc"
```

I need to show this in breadcrumbs with labels, but when click on `/bbb` call `222`

I try to handle this

```
        const url = "/aaa/2222/ccc"
        const label = "/aaa/bbb/ccc"
        breadcrumbs: any;
        
        
        this.breadcrumbs = url.split('/')
              .reduce((acc, cur, i) => {

                const url1 = i === 0
                  ? `${acc[i - 1].url1}/${label.split('/')[i]}`
                  : undefined;

                const label1 = i === 0
                  ? `${acc[i - 1].label1}/${url.split('/')[i]}`
                  : undefined;

                const breadcrumb = {
                  url1,
                  label1
                };
                acc.push(breadcrumb);

                return acc;
              }, []);
              
              var numbers = [175, 50, 25];
```

But this is output, and this is not correct

`/aaa/bbb/ccc/aaa/bbb/ccc/aaa/sites/bbb/ccc/aaa/222`

I need in UI `aaa/bbb/ccc` but in background `aaa/222/ccc`

Thnx

Comment: Please can you update the snippet so that it runs and gives the output in the question? At the moment it gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to build up an array of objects containing a label and url section.

The following would do that for you.

```
const url = "/aaa/222/ccc"
const label = "/aaa/bbb/ccc"

createObject(url,label) {
    const urlArray = url.split("/").slice(1); 
    const labelArray = label.split("/").slice(1);
    return urlArray.map((item, index) => {
      return {url: item, label: labelArray[index]}
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the best solution. Now I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the previous accumulated url/label if `i > 0`, not when `i === 0` in your OP.

```js
const url = "/aaa/2222/ccc";
const label = "/aaa/bbb/ccc";

const urlPaths = url.split("/");
const labelPaths = label.split("/");

const snackbar = urlPaths.reduce((acc, urlPath, i) => {
    let path;
    if (i === 0) {
        path = {
            url: "",
            label: "",
        };
    } else {
        const { url, label } = acc[i-1];
        path = {
            url: `${url}/${urlPath}`,
            label: `${label}/${labelPaths[i]}` 
        };
    }

    acc.push(path);
    return acc;
}, []).splice(1);


console.log(snackbar);
```

Outputs

```json
[{
  "url": "/aaa",
  "label": "/aaa"
}, {
  "url": "/aaa/2222",
  "label": "/aaa/bbb"
}, {
  "url": "/aaa/2222/ccc",
  "label": "/aaa/bbb/ccc"
}]
```

EDIT: the `.splice(1)` trailing call removes the first snackbar path (which has empty strings for the URL/label).